# What does zero in zero point energy refers to?

Tags: energy, terminology, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, vacuum

I know due to Heisenberg uncertainty principle even empty space can have lots of particles constantly popping in and out of existence, this also means that absolute zero cannot exist but what does zero refer to in this context?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy

Comment: @annav according to wiki it is the lowest possible energy that any quantum object can have which is zero but zero is not allowed by Heisenberg uncertainty principle, so this zero point is fluctuating? so this is what causing lamb shift found in hydrogen atom right?

Comment: The ground state is *defined* as *zero-point*, not zero the real number.  Just to point out there are no lower bound states. The heisenberg uncertainty is a rule of thumb,  it can be shown to come out of the commutation relations in the rigorous theory, the one which calculates the ground state. The vacuum fluctuations do affect  the exact levels in the calculations.  see my anser here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/382704/what-are-quantum-fluctuations-really/387793#387793

Comment: For particles to come out of vacuum fluctuations energy should be supplied from real particles. They do not just pop in and out . see an example of zero point energy here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hosc4.html

Comment: @annv just like the ground state of electron in atom the ground state of vacuum is not zero, but unlike electron in atom you're saying vacuum do not have different energy states. So zero point energy in vacuum is not a true zero that's what it is all about, man I'm good.